# Select the row with the specific order value in each group

Tags: r

I would like to keep row  df1 by column `grade` under order of priority (2 > -8 > 1)

Here is a part of example:

```
> df1
       ID  grade   col1   col2
1  AMM115      2      1     23
2  AMM115      1      1     23
3  AMM115      2      1     23
4  AGM132     -8      2     24
5  AGM132      1      2     24
6  ARM028     -8      1     28
7  ASM019     -8      2     17
8  AHM172     -8      2     63
9  ARM028      2      1     28
10 AHM172      2      2     63
```

How could I keep row for each `ID` under the priority, and then.
The resulting would like this:

```
> df2

       ID  grade   col1   col2
1  AMM115      2      1     23
4  AGM132     -8      2     24
7  ASM019     -8      2     17
9  ARM028      2      1     28
10 AHM172      2      2     63
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` version `1.1.0`, we can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   arrange(ID, ordered(grade, c(2, -8, 1))) %>%
   slice_head(n = 1, by = 'ID')
```

-output

```
       ID grade col1 col2
4  AGM132    -8    2   24
10 AHM172     2    2   63
1  AMM115     2    1   23
9  ARM028     2    1   28
7  ASM019    -8    2   17
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(match(grade, c(2, -8, 1))), head(.SD, 1), ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `factor` with `levels=` in specific order.

```
dat$grade <- factor(dat$grade, levels=c(2, -8, 1))

unique(dat[with(dat, ave(as.integer(grade), ID, FUN=\(x) x == min(x))) == 1, ])
#        ID grade
# 1  AMM115     2
# 4  AGM132    -8
# 7  ASM019    -8
# 9  ARM028     2
# 10 AHM172     2
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c("AMM115", "AMM115", "AMM115", "AGM132", 
"AGM132", "ARM028", "ASM019", "AHM172", "ARM028", "AHM172"), 
    grade = c(2L, 1L, 2L, -8L, 1L, -8L, -8L, -8L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: hi, thank you for answer, I tried to used on my real data (with many columns), it's seem get some error, I tried to  figure out where need to modify.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `match` to find desired order and use `which.min` to subset for the lowest match.

```
do.call(rbind,
   lapply(split(df1, df1$ID), \(x) x[which.min(match(x$grade, c(2, -8, 1))),]))
#           ID grade col1 col2
#AGM132 AGM132    -8    2   24
#AHM172 AHM172     2    2   63
#AMM115 AMM115     2    1   23
#ARM028 ARM028     2    1   28
#ASM019 ASM019    -8    2   17
```

Data

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
       ID  grade   col1   col2
1  AMM115      2      1     23
2  AMM115      1      1     23
3  AMM115      2      1     23
4  AGM132     -8      2     24
5  AGM132      1      2     24
6  ARM028     -8      1     28
7  ASM019     -8      2     17
8  AHM172     -8      2     63
9  ARM028      2      1     28
10 AHM172      2      2     63")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option:

```
 merge(unique(d1),aggregate(grade~ID,transform(d1, grade=ordered(grade, c(2,-8,1))), min))

      ID grade col1 col2
1 AGM132    -8    2   24
2 AHM172     2    2   63
3 AMM115     2    1   23
4 ARM028     2    1   28
5 ASM019    -8    2   17

distinct(d) %>%
  slice_min(factor(grade, c(2, -8, 1)), by = ID)

       ID grade col1 col2
1  AMM115     2    1   23
4  AGM132    -8    2   24
9  ARM028     2    1   28
7  ASM019    -8    2   17
10 AHM172     2    2   63
```